# FormView validation on fields not from form

Tags: django, django-views

I am writing a `FormView` which will add for example a comment on `Person` object.

I want to check if current user wrote a comment for this `Person` and if he did I'd like to raise `Http404`.

Question: What is the best place for this validation? I don't want to call validation in `get_context_data` and `form_valid`. Is `dispatch` method a good place for this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `form_valid` will only be called when you POST the form so that won't work as GET requests will still render. You could therefore put it in the `get` method for the `FormView` which would prevent the view and template loading the initial form. The drawback is that people could technically still POST to that URL if they really wanted to.

As you mentioned, I would put it in the `dispatch` method. It is very early in the cycle of the `FormView` so you avoid unnecessary processing.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # I'm just guessing your Comment/Person models
    user = self.request.user
    try:
        person = Person.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    except:
        raise Http404("No user exists")
    if Comment.objects.filter(content_object=person).exist():
        raise Http404("Comment already exists")
    return super(MyFormView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**EDIT** [This is a good link describing the various ways you can decorate your class based view to add permission and user checking](http://jsatt.com/blog/decorators-vs-mixins-for-django-class-based-views/)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this mixin

```
class PermissionCheckMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, perm=None, obj=None):
        self.perm = perm
        self.obj = obj

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_anonymous():
            if request.is_ajax():
                return JSONResponseForbidden()
            else:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()

        elif request.user.is_authenticated():
            if self.perm:
                if request.user.has_perm(self.perm, self.obj):
                    return super(PermissionCheckMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    if request.is_ajax():
                        return JSONResponseForbidden()
                    else:
                        return HttpResponseForbidden()
            else:
                if request.is_ajax():
                    return JSONResponseForbidden()
                else:
                    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

And use it like this:

```
class TestFormView(PermissionCheckMixin, FormView):
    ...
```

You can easily adapt this mixin, somehow like this:

```
def __init__(self, pk):
    self.person_pk = pk

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.user.pk == self.person_pk:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
```